# How to add length to a vector 3 to get a new vector

Tags: three.js

I am working with a vector 3 where I have source vector3 position.
I am trying to create a new vector 5 meter away from the source position on X axis.

here is the graphical presentation for it.
[image]

I tried following this document but could not find to make above thing work
so can someone help me with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to create a new vector 5 meter

The problem with this statement is that you also need to specify a direction. Only then you can create a displacement vector that you can add to your source point in order to compute the target point. Try it like so:

```js
const distance = 5;
const direction = new Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ); // unit length
 
const displacement = new Vector3().copy( direction ).multiplyScalar( distance );
const targetPoint = new Vector3().copy( sourcePoint ).add( displacement );
```